# Adding headers to ORION inquiries

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm currently working in an environment where several ORION Context Brokers (OCBs) are deployed and I'm guessing how to include headers in the enquiries.

I mean, when one of the OCBs communicates with other OCB and wants to add additional headers, how it should be handled (if there is a way to)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the comunication is done using notifications (i.e. OCB1 is subscribed to OCB2, so OCB1 receives notifications from OCB2), you could use the NGSIv2 custom notifications functionality in order to include custom headers.

See "Custom notifications" section in the [NGSIv2 specification document](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/). Pay special attention to the `headers` field within `httpCustom`.